# What causes CBCentralManagerStateUnknown in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-bluetooth

Why do I get `CBCentralManagerStateUnknown` on an iPad 2 when using this simple code?

```
- (BOOL)viewDidLoad {

    bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateResetting) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateResetting");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnknown");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported");

}
```

I cannot figure out what `CBCentralManagerStateUnknown` means. What do I do? The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html) just say:

> State unknown, update imminent.

I get this response with a Bluetooth device connected, and also when Bluetooth is off.
If I try to run something like `[manager retrieveConnectedPeripherals]`, I also get this message in the console:

```
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBConcreteCentralManager: ...> is not powered on
```

Comment: It means the state is unknown. In this case, probably because the Bluetooth hardware hasn't booted up yet. What's the problem?

Comment: I cannot get it to the state `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn` so that I can do anything. What do I have to do to get it to that state?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. You did mention that "I get this response with a Bluetooth device connected", but you also indicated that you can't do anything. How do you have the device connected in the first place then?

Comment: For one thing, the iPad 2 lacks Bluetooth LE support, so Core Bluetooth will not work with it. That should return CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported, but maybe there's a slight bug in the way this is being checked.

Comment: @Brad Larsen, I think you are mistaken, I have an iPad2 and it has BLE support.  I have used it extensively for dev with a BLE 4.0 peripheral that I designed, it has been invaluable.  More info: Its currently running iOS 7.1, model is FD328LL/A.  Perhaps not all iPad2 models have BLE support?  An easy check is to download the app LightBlue LE and run it, if your peripheral is configured to begin Advertising upon scan, then it will show up .

Comment: @DasBoos - You might be confusing the iPad 2 with the iPad Air 2. The iPad 2 only supported Bluetooth 2.1, not 4.0 / BTLE: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp622?locale=en_US . The iPad 2 I have as a test device lacks BTLE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know why delegate is never called. Because the object is deleted from memory. Just make a strong property

`@property (strong, nonatomic) DiscoverBluetoothDevices *btDevices;`

And in init

```
@implementation DiscoverBluetoothDevices
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES}];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And now delegate is called properly.

Comment: Try to change your code from [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]options:nil]; with NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey]; [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:dictionary];

Answer (score 3):

`CBCentralManagerStateUnknown` simply means iOS has started the BLE process, but has not completed initialization. Give it a moment, and the state will change.

In general, you will "give it a moment" by detecting a state chang in a `CBCentralManagerDelegate` delegate handler rather than looking at it right after the initialization call. You will implement

```
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState: (CBCentralManager *) central;
```

There are some good examples that show this, such as Apple's [heart rate monitor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html).

Comment: I have a breakpoint in that function, but the function never gets called.

Comment: I have the same problem centralManagerDidUpdateState never get called

Comment: Depending on what you're been doing up to this point, one thing you might try is restarting your iOS device. I've seen iOS get confused about BLE links in the past, generally when multiple apps are used to connect to a single device. Rebooting the device is often the only thing that seems to clear up the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If a central's state goes to `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` (while Bluetooth Low Energy is supported by the device) it most likely means the app has done something bad with CoreBluetooth.

Check the [iOS Bluetooth Diagnostic Logging](http://developer.apple.com/bluetooth) logs.

For example, if you do this...

`_cm1 = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: @"not_unique" }];
  _cm2 = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: @"not_unique" }];`

... the second central's state will go to `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer (old question I know); start a scan for peripherals, this will start BT LE up and your delegates will get called back.  My Delegates and state info did not change until I did this.

a. Setup your cbcentralmanager as below
b. Have the -central* delegates in your code and  in your .h file
c. NSLog or have a label on screen update with new status. And... Success.

```
cManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

[cManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES}];
```

Comment: This answer is sufficient to get this going.

Answer (score 1):

You need to both retain the `CBCentralManager` instance (put it in an ivar or private property) and wait for the state change delegate to be called. (The state is always "unknown" if you check it immediately after instantiating the manager. The real state will appear momentarily in the delegate method.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did use AppDelegate as delegate for

```
CBCentralManagerDelegate
```

and indirectional for

```
 AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate.
```

in one time.

1) Take care about threads. Use

```
dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

or

```
[NSThread mainThread]
```

for work with BLE.

2) Take care about using this 2 delegates on 1 object. Because hardware is **NOT thead and context** save