# does xamarin supports coreBluetooth for iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, xamarin.mobile

I am new to Xamarin, and performing a feasibility study.

I am not sure if Xamarin provides a Common API for Bluetooth Low energy across platforms including iOS, android, Windows? In iOS, this API is coreBluetooth.

Please provide details; I couldn't find any good information when searching the net.

Answer (score 6):

Yes Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android do support Bluetooth.

No, they do not supply a common API

---

For my Sphero hacking - I wrote a cross platform BlueTooth Sphero-specific module https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/tree/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Plugins/Sphero

On iOS this module used ExternalAccessory rather than CoreBLuetooth - just because that is the way Sphero works, but on the other platforms Sphero uses Bluetooth SPP

If you need some CoreBluetooth sample code, then I wrote and tested some code in http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/7576/ and [Solving 'CBConcreteCentralManager is not powered on' in Core Bluetooth in MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657695/solving-cbconcretecentralmanager-is-not-powered-on-in-core-bluetooth-in-monoto/13660275#13660275)